# Editing an object in a Listbox and the list where it comes from

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, python-3.4

I started making a function that when a selection in a listbox is double clicked, the selection info(a dictionary) gets returned.

```
def OnDouble(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        selection = widget.curselection()
        value = widget.get(selection[0])
```

What I want is to be able to take that selection that gets returned and edit it's contents. By doing this, any changes in content should show up in the listbox and the list from which it comes from.

Example of value that gets returned with double click:

```
{'Num Tel/Cel': 'test1', 'Email': 'test1', 'Fecha de Entrega': '', 'Orden Creada:': ' Tuesday, June 23, 2015', 'Nombre': 'test1', 'Num Orden': '1'}
```

Comment: I was thinking of using the same function that creates this dictionaries as a way to edit them.. is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from Tkinter import *

oneThing = {"Name:": "Guido", "Tel.:":"666-6969", "Email:":"foobar@lol.com"}
another = {"Name:": "Philler", "Tel.:":"111-1111", "Email:":"philler@lol.com"}
z = [oneThing, another]

root = Tk()
l = Listbox(root)
l.pack(fill = "both")
l.pack_propagate(True)
[l.insert(END, item) for item in z]

def createPerson(index):

    #This is whatever function that creates stuff

    def edit():

        for i in range(len(labels)):
            z[index][labels[i]] = entries[i].get()
        print z
        top.destroy()

    top = Toplevel()
    labels = ["Name:", "Tel.:", "Email:"]
    i = 0
    for text in labels:
        Label(top, text = text).grid(column = 0, row = i)
        i += 1

    e1 = Entry(top)
    e1.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
    e2 = Entry(top)
    e2.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
    e3 = Entry(top)
    e3.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
    Button(top, text = "Submit", command = edit).grid(column = 1, row = 3)
    entries = [e1, e2, e3]

    #Return reference to toplevel so that root can wait for it to run its course
    return top

def edit():
    global l, z, root
    # Get dictionary from listbox
    sel = l.curselection()
    if len(sel) > 0:
        indexToEdit = z.index(eval(l.get(sel[0])))
        l.delete(sel)
        root.wait_window(createPerson(indexToEdit))
        print z[indexToEdit]
        l.insert(sel, z[indexToEdit])

Button(root, text = "Edit", command = edit).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**Edit**: Example now shows a way to edit elements on the fly based on user input; uses `Toplevel()` widget to accept input.

Comment: I would like to edit the dicts. with the same func the creates the. I have this tkwindow where the user inputs the data(name, email, phone num, etc.). This way, maybe when the window pops , in the entry fields, the contents of the selection I want to edit already show up..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functions given in this [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm) for editing the selections of a listbox.

Example -

```
widget.selection_set(<item to add>) # adds an item to the selection
```

or

```
widget.selection_clear(<item to remove>) # removes the item from the selection
```

Documentation for `selection_set` - [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.selection_set-method)
Documentation for `selection_clear` - [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.selection_clear-method)